# Troubleshooting "preg_replace(): Unknown modifier"

Tags: php

I am trying to implement an open source string-to-link converter, but i have an error and I frankly have tried everything and do not know what is wrong.  Here is the code:

```
$chatmessage = preg_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)',
'<a href="'.$chatmessage.'" target=_blank
style="color:#6B6B6B;">'.$chatmessage.'</a>', $chatmessage);
```

Here is the error that I get:

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '(' in /echogetconversation.php on line 38.  line 38, is this:

```
'<a href="'.$chatmessage.'" target=_blank
style="color:#6B6B6B;">'.$chatmessage.'</a>', $chatmessage);
```

If anyone could assist me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you exactly wants to do??

Comment: I just want to get rid of the error.  It is supposed to input text that begins with www. and turn it into a clikcable link

Comment: ur pattern is really very confusing.

Comment: I think that I just solved it dude; thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (causing the error message) is you've set the delimiters to be `(...)` but then you are using `(` and `)` in your pattern. You could mess around with escaping, but choosing a different delimiter is simpler.

EDIT: looking at it again, I think you intended the parentheses for capture, so your problem is you forgot the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)!